# jQuery/Ajax simple form post in webmatrix

Tags: ajax, jquery, razor, webmatrix

Can someone please tell me the code I need, so that this form updates the database without needing a refresh?

```
@{
Layout = "~/_template1.cshtml";

var db = Database.Open("stayinflorida");
var CurrentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
var userdetails = ("SELECT * from UserProfile WHERE UserId='8'");
var quserdetails = db.QuerySingle(userdetails, CurrentUser);

if (IsPost){
var updateuserdetails = "UPDATE UserProfile SET FirstName = @0, LastName = @1 WHERE UserID='8'";
db.Execute(updateuserdetails, Request["FirstName"], Request["LastName"]);
}
}

<h1>My Details</h1>
<hr>
<form method="post" action="~/Account/MyDetails.cshtml">
<fieldset>
<label>First Name</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@quserdetails.FirstName">
<br>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input class="input-xlarge" type="text" name="LastName" placeholder=".input-xlarge" value="@quserdetails.LastName">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cancel</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

What I have written kind of works, but I have to hit F5 for it to update, and it's just not what I want. I want to use jQuery/ajax, but I just don't know the code.

Comment: i forgot to add, i set the action to just post back to the same page.

Comment: I had a problem with AJAX in WebMatrix, too, at first but if you are still monitoring this post I will help you if I can. No you do not need any additional library outside of the jQuery library, as that is the only way that I know how to do it as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need some JavaScript if you want to use AJAX. The jQuery library simplifies this. Here's an article I wrote that features AJAX updates using WebMatrix: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/176/WebMatrix-and-jQuery-Forms-Part-2-Editing-Data

Comment: so the jquery library is the only thing i need to load to make this happen? I thought there may be an additional ajax library i'd need to load too?

Comment: jQuery has all the AJAX support you will need: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/