# How do I get an SQL value to use in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, webmatrix

I am creating a cshtml site on Microsoft WebMatrix. I have figured out how to display a value from an SQL table:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("userBands");
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM userBands ORDER BY bandName";
}

 @foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString)){           
        <tr>
            <td>@row.email</td>
            <td id="bandName">@row.bandName</td>
            <td id="wwTech">@row.wwTech</td>
            <td id="bTech">@row.bTech</td>
            <td id="hd">@row.hd</td>
            <td id="l">@row.l</td>
            <td id="rc">@row.rc</td>
            <td id="r">@row.r</td>
        </tr>
   }
```

...but have not been able to figure out how to pull one of these values into JavaScript. It seems like AJAX will be part of the solution, but I'm having a really hard time finding examples of something this simple. How do I get one of these values as a JavaScript string for use in that logic?

Comment: related if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601859/jquery-ajax-simple-form-post-webmatrix

Comment: Thanks. I had found that article but I am very inexperienced and so needed something more specifically directed at what I want to do instead of just how to use the functions in general.